# Preparing Data with NAs for Sparse Matrix and XGBOOST

Tags: r, matrix, na, xgboost

I have a large data set consisting of factor variables, numeric variables, and a target column I'm trying to properly feed into xgboost with the objective of making an xgb.Matrix and training a model.

I'm confused about the proper processing to get my dataframe into an xgb.DMatrix object.  Specifically, I have NAs in both factor and numeric variables and I want to make a sparse.model.matrix from my dataframe before creating the xgb.Matrix.  The proper handling of the NAs is really messing me up.

I have the following sample dataframe `df` consisting of one binary categorical variable, two continuous variables, and a target.  the categorical variable and one continuous variable has NAs

```
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ v1    : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 2 1 NA 2 1 1 NA 2
 $ v2    : num  3.2 5.4 8.3 NA 7.1 8.2 9.4 NA 9.9 4.2
 $ v3    : num  22.1 44.1 57 64.2 33.1 56.9 71.2 33.9 89.3 97.2
 $ target: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1

     v1  v2   v3 target
1     0 3.2 22.1      0
2     1 5.4 44.1      0
3     1 8.3 57.0      1
4     0  NA 64.2      1
5  <NA> 7.1 33.1      0
6     1 8.2 56.9      0
7     0 9.4 71.2      0
8     0  NA 33.9      1
9  <NA> 9.9 89.3      0
10    1 4.2 97.2      0
```

`sparse.model.matrix` from the `matrix` library won't accept NAs.  It eliminates the rows (which I don't want).  So I'll need to change the NAs to a numeric replacement like `-999`

if I use the simple command:

```
df[is.na(df)] = -999
```

it only replaces the NAs in the numeric columns:

```
     v1     v2   v3 target
1     0    3.2 22.1      0
2     1    5.4 44.1      0
3     1    8.3 57.0      1
4     0 -999.0 64.2      1
5  <NA>    7.1 33.1      0
6     1    8.2 56.9      0
7     0    9.4 71.2      0
8     0 -999.0 33.9      1
9  <NA>    9.9 89.3      0
10    1    4.2 97.2      0
```

So I first (think I) need to change the factor variables to numeric and then do 
the substitution.  Doing that I get:

```
     v1     v2   v3 target
1     1    3.2 22.1      0
2     2    5.4 44.1      0
3     2    8.3 57.0      1
4     1 -999.0 64.2      1
5  -999    7.1 33.1      0
6     2    8.2 56.9      0
7     1    9.4 71.2      0
8     1 -999.0 33.9      1
9  -999    9.9 89.3      0
10    2    4.2 97.2      0
```

but converting the factor variable back to a factor (I think this is necessary
so xgboost will later know its a factor) I get three levels:

```
data.frame':    10 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ v1    : Factor w/ 3 levels "-999","1","2": 2 3 3 2 1 3 2 2 1 3
 $ v2    : num  3.2 5.4 8.3 -999 7.1 8.2 9.4 -999 9.9 4.2
 $ v3    : num  22.1 44.1 57 64.2 33.1 56.9 71.2 33.9 89.3 97.2
 $ target: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1
```

I'm ultimately not sure now that making the sparse.model.matrix and ultimately
the xgb.matrix object will be meaningful because v1 appears messed up.

To make matters more confusing, `xgb.Dmatrix()` has an argument `missing`
that I can use to identify numeric values (-999) that represent NAs. But this
can only be used for a dense matrix.  If I submitted the dense matrix I'd 
just have the NAs and wouldn't need that.  However, in the sparse matrix
where I have -999s, I can't use it.

I hope I'm not overlooking something easy.  Been through [xgboost.pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xgboost/xgboost.pdf) extensively and looked on Google.

Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to make a sparse matrix if you have only 3 predictors? Secondly, `xgboost` only accepts numerical features.

Comment: 1. my real dataset has 185 predictors and 70000 observations. 2. xgboost accepts categorical variables (I think) when changed to numeric form (0,1)s like Ive done.

Comment: You can just use `options(na.action='na.pass'); sm<-sparse.model.matrix(target~.,df)`, then feed it into `xgboost`. The sparse matrix will only contain non-missing values either way for your dummy variables. For continuous vars, a missing(default) direction is learnt.

Comment: @mtoto Thx.  Why do I see people replacing NAs with -9999 all over the place and then making sparse matrices?

Comment: See [here](http://info.salford-systems.com/blog/bid/142415/A-Reminder-About-Missing-Values-In-Data-Mining). If you think your `NA`'s are not randomly distributed, you can convert them to a non-missing value and see if it has predictive power.

Answer (score 3):

`options(na.action='na.pass')` as mentioned by @mtoto is the best way to deal with this problem. It will make sure that you don't loose any data while building model matrix.

Specifically XGBoost implementation; in case of NAs, check for higher gain when doing the splits while growing tree. So for example if splits without considering NAs is decided to be a variable `var1`'s (range `[0,1]`) value 0.5 then it calculates the gain considering `var1` NAs to be < 0.5 and > 0.5. To whatever split direction it gets more gain it attributes NAs to have that split direction. So NAs now have a range `[0,0.5]` or `[0.5,1]` but not actual value assigned to it (i.e. imputed). Refer (original author tqchen's [comment](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/21) on Aug 12, 2014).

If you are imputing -99xxx there then you are limiting the algorithm ability to learn NA's proper range (conditional on labels).